# Redis on Azure - suddenly keys stop increasing, hits & misses zero

Tags: azure, caching, redis

We are running a setup on Azure consisting:

- S3 web app in UK South
- S2 failover in UK West
- 200DTU Elastic Pool with around 25 databases
- Redis server

Several times this week, we have had periods where Redis has stopped hitting and missing data, and no additional items are being added to the cache. In effect the caching completely ceases being available.

Flushing the cache does not make any difference to the issue - nothing is added, nothing is hit or even missed.

The only way to re-enable is to restart the web app itself. After which everything is back to normal.

Our developers are looking into potential causes in our codebase, but I wonder if anyone has any ideas on how to diagnose or solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If restarting your web app fixes it, it sounds like some contention on the client side. You might find [this](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/db0e90bedeb3fc4823c2#file-diagnoserediserrors-clientside-md) (https://gist.github.com/JonCole/db0e90bedeb3fc4823c2#file-diagnoserediserrors-clientside-md) link useful. It could likely be threadpool or CPU contention on the client machines hosting your web app.